# Replace Parameter Value in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Currently, I am training my agent and I am wondering if someone asks a question is it possible to change a parameter value to what you know it would be. So for example if someone asks `do you have any beers` can I can change the parameter to be `beer` instead of `beers`. Another example is if someone asks `do you have any Johnny` can I change the parameter to be `Johnnie Walker` instead of `Johnny`

If this can be done how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by creating [developer entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities) for the different beverage types. This way you would define one "standard" term, and then add the other terms that alias to it.

Answer (score 0):

In a developer entity, always the highlighted value in the [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK7Wa.png) is the value identified.
In your case, you can have the word "beer" and "beer","beers" as synonyms of it. So that when a user says beers/beer the identified keyword will be "beer".